# Why is my Magento 2 child theme showing blank?

Tags: magento2

My Magento 2 child theme is showing without any CSS

I am trying to extend a child theme. The existing theme is working fine, but the newly extended child theme of the existing child is showing content without CSS.

How do I fix this?

Comment: have you mention parent theme name in theme.xml file ?

Answer (score 0):

Run the below commands :

```
rm -rf var/*
rm -rf pub/static/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
chmod -R 7777 var pub/static
```